# Types of function's parameters are not considered when imported from a commonjs module in TS

Tags: node.js, typescript, parameters, require, commonjs

I'm a beginner to TS, in this example I have a module `model.ts`, where I export a function with a param

```
// model.ts
function go(name: string) {
    console.log(typeof name);
    return name;
}
export { go };
```

And when I try to import this module in the `index.ts` and use, I'm able to pass any type of params like

```
// index.ts
const { go } = require('./model.js');

console.log(go('typescript'));
console.log(go(1));
console.log(go(1.7));
console.log(go(false));
```

The above code just works fine, without respecting the type of params of the imported 'go' function, and outputs;

```
string
typescript

number
1

number
1.7

boolean
false
```

Is this the behaviour of TS imported functions and classes, or am I missing anything to consider the types of the params too?

Comment: You should be using `import` to import typescript files. When compiled, the [module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) tsconfig setting defines how `import` and `export` are transformed, if necessary.